# Read in .xlsx with csv module in python

Tags: python, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read in an excel file with .xlsx formatting with the `csv` module, but I'm not having any luck with it when using an excel file even with my dialect and encoding specified. Below, I show my different attempts and error results with the different encodings I tried. If anyone could point me into the correct coding, syntax or module I could use to read in a .xlsx file in Python, I'd appreciate it.

With the below code, I get the following error: `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, csv

with open('filelocation.xlsx', "r+", encoding="Latin1")  as inputFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inputFile, dialect='excel')
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

With the below code, I get the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 16: invalid continuation byte`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, csv

with open('filelocation.xlsx', "r+", encoding="Latin1")  as inputFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inputFile, dialect='excel')
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

When I use `utf-16` in the `encoding`, I get the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 570-571: illegal UTF-16 surrogate`

Comment: You cannot read an xlsx file using csv module. Excel dialect only means that you can read CSV files that were created using Excel.

Comment: do you know of any modules that can read .xlsx files?

Comment: There are lots of modules you can find using a Google search, but you should test them to see if they fit to your use case.

Comment: Redaction of the question is impeccable, it really helped me, even without reading any answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

You cannot use Python's `csv` library for reading `xlsx` formatted files. You need to install and use a different library. For example, you could use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/) as follows:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("filelocation.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    print(row)
```

This would display all of the rows in the file as lists of row values. The [Python Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) website gives other possible examples.

---

Alternatively you could create a list of rows:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("filelocation.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

data = list(ws.iter_rows(values_only=True))

print(data)
```

---

Note: If you are using the older Excel format `.xls`, you could instead use the `xlrd` library. This no longer supports the `.xlsx` format though.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("filelocation.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [sheet.row_values(rowx) for rowx in range(sheet.nrows)]

print(data)
```

Comment: I like that you recommended `xlrd`, as I believe it's the best Excel reader. But if you want a list of the values in a row, that is more easily (and probably more efficiently) accomplished by simply `cols = sheet.row_values(row)` instead of your list comprehension. Also, I recommend using some other name for the row *index* (I'm partial to `rx`; you'll see a lot of examples use `rowx`) because the name `row` so often refers to a row *object*.

Comment: You can no longer use xlrd on xlsx files <a href="url">link text</a><br><br>
To read xlsx files either <br><br>
(not recommended unless you have an outstanding reason to stick with xlrd)<br>
convert the file into xls manually before processing<br><br>
(recommended)<br>
use the newer openpyxl python module as recommended <a href="http://www.python-excel.org/">here</a>
(also recommended)<br>
use pandas excel_file module

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very very rough implementation using just the standard library.

```
def xlsx(fname, sheet=1):
    import zipfile
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fname)
    strings = [el.text for e, el in iterparse(z.open('xl/sharedStrings.xml')) if el.tag.endswith('}t')]
    rows = []
    row = {}
    value = ''
    for e, el in iterparse(z.open('xl/worksheets/sheet%s.xml' % sheet)):
        if el.tag.endswith('}v'):  # <v>84</v>
            value = el.text
        if el.tag.endswith('}c'):  # <c r="A3" t="s"><v>84</v></c>
            if el.attrib.get('t') == 's':
                value = strings[int(value)]
            column_name = ''.join(x for x in el.attrib['r'] if not x.isdigit())  # AZ22
            row[column_name] = value
            value = ''
        if el.tag.endswith('}row'):
            rows.append(row)
            row = {}
    return rows
```

(This is copied from a deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371163/reading-xlsx-files-using-python )

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very very rough implementation using just the standard library.

```
def xlsx(fname):
    import zipfile
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fname)
    strings = [el.text for e, el in iterparse(z.open('xl/sharedStrings.xml')) if el.tag.endswith('}t')]
    rows = []
    row = {}
    value = ''
    for e, el in iterparse(z.open('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml')):
        if el.tag.endswith('}v'):  # <v>84</v>
            value = el.text
        if el.tag.endswith('}c'):  # <c r="A3" t="s"><v>84</v></c>
            if el.attrib.get('t') == 's':
                value = strings[int(value)]
            letter = el.attrib['r'] # AZ22
            while letter[-1].isdigit():
                letter = letter[:-1]
            row[letter] = value
            value = ''
        if el.tag.endswith('}row'):
            rows.append(row)
            row = {}
    return rows
```

This answer is copied from a deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22067980/131881

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use Python's csv library for reading .xlsx formatted files. You also can't use "pd.read_excel" which is a travesty (it only supports .xls). The below is a function I created to import .xlsx. It assigns the columns names on the first row of the file you import. Pretty straight forward.

```
def import_xlsx(filepath):
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filepath, data_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    df = list(ws.iter_rows(values_only=True))
    new=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
    new1=new[1:]
    new1.columns=new[0:1].values[0].tolist()
    return(new1)
```

Example:

```
new_df=import_xlsx('C:\\Users\big_boi\\documents\\my_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: As of pandas 1.3.0, read_excel supports .xlsx via the default openpyxl engine.