# Appropriate Time to Dynamically Set Variable Names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: Turns out the answer is an emphatic "no". However, I'm still struggling to populate the lists with the right amount of entries.

---

I've been searching StackOverflow all over for this, and I keep seeing that dynamically setting variable names is not a good solution. However, I can't think of another way to to this.

I have a `DataFrame` created from `pandas` (read in from excel) that has columns with string headers and integer entries, and one column that has the numbers (let's call it Week) 1 through 52 increasing sequentially. What I want to do is create separate lists each named for the column headers and the entry is the week number appearing the number of times of the listed integer.

This is simple for a few columns, just manually create lists names, but as the number of columns grows, this could get a little out of hand.

Atrocious explanation, it was the best I could come up with. Hopefully a simplified example will clarify.

```
week  str1    str2    str3   
1       8       2        5        
2       1       0        3    
3       2       1        1
```

Desired output:

```
str1_count = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3] # eight 1's, one 2, and two 3's
str2_count = [1, 1, 3]                         # two 1's, one 3
str3_count = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]       # five 1's, three 2's, one 3
```

What I have so far:

```
results = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(from_csv(...., sep = ","))
for key in df:
    for i in df[key]
        results[key] = i # this only creates a list with the int value of the most recent i
```

Comment: Why do they need to be variables? Why can't you use a dictionary keyed by the name instead?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, why not use a dictionary

Comment: I thought dictionaries were constructed by many unique `key:value` pairs. I need lots of values stored in one list (eventually to create a separate excel file for each list)... Or am I misunderstanding how dictionaries work? Could I have `{str1: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}`? or `{str1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]}`. If so how would I set that up?

Comment: The value can be a list.

Comment: I did not know the value could be a list. So the latter example in my comment would work. Ha! Turns out all those answers saying "use a dictionary" were all on to something! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, like this?

```
import collections
import csv
import io

reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO('''
week,str1,str2,str3
1,8,2,5
2,1,0,3
3,2,1,1
'''.strip()))

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in reader:
    for key in ('str1', 'str2', 'str3'):
        data[key].extend([row['week']]*int(row[key]))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict(data))

# Output:
{'str1': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '3'],
 'str2': ['1', '1', '3'],
 'str3': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3']}
```

Note: Pandas is good for crunching data and doing some interesting operations on it, but if you just need something simple you don't need it. This is one of those cases.

Comment: Thanks! I was using just using Pandas to read data in from Excel, but I'll use the `csv` module from now on for simple things.

Comment: You can [read them without using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35745283/344286), though if you have Pandas there's nothing wrong with using it to read your excel file, I'm sure.