# Python: Scanning an Excel template and filling in values

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel template that I'm trying to write values to from a another Excel file containing the required data to. Is there a way I can scan the template and fill in the values using Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read in .xlsx with csv module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744613/read-in-xlsx-with-csv-module-in-python)

Comment: The information here is not complete enough to tell. Elaborate further. Also have a look here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Answer (score 0):

You can [export the excel file to csv](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/04/24/convert-excel-csv/) (it's an old article but the idea is the same, I don't know how excel is now), then use [python CSV I/O](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to manipulate the file and save it.

Excel will be able to open the generated CSV without any problem of any sort.