# How to update excel column values based on dictionary in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks like:

expense.xlsx

```
|Amount|CategoryId|Date|
|:----|:------:|-----:|
| 123 | 1 | 2020-07-07|
| 321| 2 | 2020-07-07|
```

I have a dictionary for the categories:

```
catDict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
```

How would I go about changing the excel column "CategoryId" to match the dictionary values:

| Amount | CategoryId | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a | 2020-07-07 |
| 321 | b | 2020-07-07 |

Answer (score 0):

Using openpyxl you can try with the following:

```
import openpyxl as opxl
wb = opxl.load_workbook('expense.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for i in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    ws['B'+str(i)] = str(ws['B'+str(i)].value).replace('1','a').replace('2','b')
wb.save('expense.xlsx')
```

If you have a lot more values to replace, then I suggest also checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) question to improve on that part of the code.

Old answer:
Can you use pandas? If so, you can use `.replace()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('expense.xlsx') #Read excel
catDict = {1:'a',2:'b'}

df['CategoryId'] = df['CategoryId'].replace(catDict)
#Alternatively one can use `.map()`

df.to_excel('expense.xlsx') #Save back to excel
```

Comment: I don't believe I can (for an assignment).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930653/python-decoding-excel-sheet-without-pandas

Comment: I can use openpyxl if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Using openpyxl, hope this helps!

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
dict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}

sheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value='Amount')
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value='CategoryId')
sheet.cell(row=1, column=3, value='Date')
row, column = 2,1
for key, values in dict.items():
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=column, value=key)
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=column+1, value=values)
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=column+2, value='2020-07-07')
    row += 1
file_name = 'sample.xlsx'
workbook.save(filename=file_name)
```